# JSON MediaType in Jersey

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I've created a WebApp that make CRUD operations using a REST server. I use java Jersey and gradle.
When I do a POST operation, I send the object in JSON format, as follows:

```
ToDo t = new ToDo(...); // Object to be posted
Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8091/todos")
                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .post(Entity.entity(t, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

But it throws an exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class todos.ToDo, genericType=class todos.ToDo.
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath (group: 'com.sahlbach.gradle', name: 'gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin', version: '1.9.+')
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jettyEclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'


repositories {
   mavenCentral()                                               
}

dependencies {
   providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
   compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.3.1'
}
```

[Here my full project](https://github.com/javiertello/Lab2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need a provider to process the JSON. JAX-RS uses `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodWriter` to marshal and unmarshal different content types. JSON isn't supported out the box. We need to add a module that has the needed provider(s)

I'm not familiar with Gradle and and build file, and how to add dependencies, but with Maven, this is the dependency mentioned in [the Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html) as the preferred dependency for JSON binding support

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>#{jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

- See [Support for Common Media Type Representations](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e7656) (this is the user guide for 2.13)
- Here's a link to the [2.3 User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.3/index.html)

---

UPDATE

So it looks like with Gradle you just need to add this dependency

```
compile: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.13'
```

With this added, the provider should be auto discovered/configured by the Jersey Client